# How can I get the height information of an object?

Tags: revit-api

```
import clr

clr.AddReference('RevitAPI')
import Autodesk.Revit.DB as DB
doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document


collector = DB.FilteredElementCollector(doc)
elements = collector.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Doors).WhereElementIsNotElementType().ToElements()
print(elements)
for element in elements:
    omniClassParam = element.LookupParameter("height")
    print(omniClassParam)
```

I want to get the height of my door but this code return none to me

Answer (score 1):

You can probably read the door height from a parameter value hosted on the door. Install [RevitLookup](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RevitLookup) or some similar Revit database exploration tool and use it to snoop your RVT project to find out which parameter t use and how t access it. Reading the value of a parameter on a Revit element is also covered by every single tutorial on [getting started with the Revit API](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/about-the-author.html#2), since it is one of the most fundamental uses of the API.